# How to search a folder name at a particular location, with a wildcard character and store in a variable?

Tags: firefox, vbscript

This is the script I have written and I have mentioned the issue I am facing below.

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO, WSH, RunDefaultProfile
Dim PF, UPF

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

UPF = Wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%")
PF = Wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%")

RunDefaultProfile = """" & PF & "\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" & """" & _
                    " -CreateProfile default"

' Create the Default profile if it not exists
If NOT FSO.FolderExists (UPF & "\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\c4ssju9t.default") Then
  WSH.Run RunDefaultProfile
End if
```

Now the challenge I am facing is, Firefox creates a random `.default` folder on each machine and I can't use my `If NOT FSO.FolderExists` condition. Also I want store the `.default` folder name if already exists. I will use that to run other commands and expand my script.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the profile is stored in the file `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini`. You can read it from the file like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

configdir = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox")
inifile   = fso.BuildPath(configDir, "profiles.ini")

If fso.FileExists(inifile) Then
  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(inifile)
  Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    line = f.ReadLine
    If Left(line, 5) = "Path=" Then
      relPath = Split(line, "=")(1)
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

  f.Close
End If
```

This will get the first profile path from the INI file (if it exists).

You can then use it like this to create a missing profile:

```
profileExists = False

If Not IsEmpty(relPath) Then
  profile = fso.BuildPath(configdir, relPath)
  profileExists = fso.FolderExists(profile)
End If

If Not profileExists Then sh.Run RunDefaultProfile
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, this logic really helped me to solve the issue, I was able to complete my task. Will post the full script once its done.